# How to pass a JSF Bean value to sec:authorize tag in spring security?

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-security

I am using the tag security in my aplication this way:

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
               <h1>Admin</h1>
</sec:authorize>
```

And works fine.

Now I trying this way:

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('#{MyBean.permission}')" ><h1>Admin</h1></sec:authorize>
```

where MyBean.permission = ROLE_ADMIN, by the debugger I can see that the MyBean.permission is the correct value.

But don't works. No error is generated, but the link is no longer rendered, it's as if the user had no more that permission.

How can I pass a variable to access property from tag security?

My web.xml:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Principal/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>   

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml                        
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

My spring-security.xml:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<beans:bean id="webSecurityExpressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <beans:property name="roleHierarchy" ref="roleHierarchy" />
</beans:bean>

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="Principal/index*" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/Principal/*" access="permitAll"/>

    <form-login login-page="/Principal/index.xhtml"        
                default-target-url="/"
                authentication-failure-url="/"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/" />
</http>

<beans:bean id="customUserDetails" class="br.com.ultracar.ultracarweb.spring.security.UserDetailsServiceImpl" />

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetails" />
</authentication-manager>  

<beans:bean id="roleHierarchy" class="org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl">
    <beans:property name="hierarchy">
        <beans:value>
            ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_FIN
            ROLE_FIN > ROLE_EX
            ROLE_EX > ROLE_GUEST
        </beans:value>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

I am using spring security just for authorization, not for authentication.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: It would be interesting for me as well